# cronjob for backup only when connected to company network

Tags: backup, cron, rsync

I am running a cronjob for rsyncing my hard drive with a folder on a server within my companies network. This happens on my laptop which I also use outside that network.

My crontab looks like this:

> */30   *   *   *   *   rsync --delete -azvv -e ssh /Users/user/Work/Folder user@server:/home/user/BACKUP/

How can I make cron running this job only when the server is available?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to determine if your server is available or not. `ping` might be sufficient but is probably not ideal. As poor man's solution you could prepend your original command like this:

```
ping -c2 server >/dev/null 2>&1 && rsync --delete...
```

This means that cron will run `rsync` only if `ping` has been successful.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, this does not work. Can you do me a favour and explain me the code you have provided. I understand that the output of a two-time ping goes into the nirvana of /dev/null/ but what does 2&1 mean?

Comment: It means you're redirecting the file descriptor 2 to the same destination as file descriptor 1, in this case, 2>&1 means send STDERR to the same destination as STDOUT, that is, the bit bucket.

Comment: Joao explained quite nicely what 2>&1 does but could you give more detail about what is not working for you?

Comment: I cannot really tell what goes wrong I have added the line ping -c2 server >/dev/null 2>&1 && rsync -azvv -e ssh /Users/user/Work/Folder user@server:/home/user/BACKUP/ to my crontab and it just stopped working.

Comment: Could you just fire a `ping -c2 server` in a terminal to check if ping is really working and not blocked by some firewall inbetween?